# Why all positive, rational terminating numbers have the following form

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to prove the following statement: Let $\forall x\in \mathbb{Q}$ where $x$ terminates, $\exists p, \alpha, \beta\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x=\frac{p}{2^\alpha\cdot 5^\beta}$. It is written in this book that I am reading, and I have seen it before. I do not know why it works, and the proof is not given in the book. I can not seem to find it anywhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That only works for rational numbers that terminate.

Comment: My apologies. I left that out of the problem. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x = \overline{b_m \cdots b_1 . a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n}$.

Then, $10^n x = \overline{b_m \cdots b_1 a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n}$.

Therefore, $x = \dfrac{\overline{b_m \cdots b_1 a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n}}{10^n} = \dfrac{p}{2^n 5^n}$

Comment: That's what I needed. Your help is appreciated! Do you know any reason why the problem I had denote n as two separate variables?

Comment: That's just weird that it would do that.

Comment: @W.G. because if you simplify the fraction you would end up with different values.

Comment: What do you mean by simplify the fraction here?

Comment: Remove common factors from the numerator and the denominator.

Comment: I get what you are saying. Thank you!